# Make 1 key from 2 vigenere keys

Tags: encryption, cryptography, vigenere

I have this school assignment about Vigenere code.

I've got 2 keys: AB and XYZ. A text is encrypted twice with these keys.
The questions are:

- How to make 1 key out of those 2?
- How to make 1 key when there are 3 keys?

Comment: I guess the presumption here is that you need to use the same cipher, and not `P = D_ab|xyz (C) = D_xyz ( D_ab (C) )` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Choose the length of the combined key as the least common multiple of the key lengths.
2. Repeat each key until it fills the combined key
3. Add all the repeated keys.

For example with `AB` and `XYZ` assuming A=0:

1. The lengths are 2 and 3, the common multiple is 6.
2. `AB AB AB` and `XYZ XYZ`
3. `A+X`, `B+Y`, `A+Z`, `B+X`, `A+Y`, `B+Z` = `XZZYYA`

This algorithm works with any number of keys.

Answer (score 0):

@CodesInChaos answer is great, but let's add some math:

```
|C| = gcd(|A|, |B|)
# gcd: greatest common divisor.
```

Also notice that you can compute the value of the combined key:

```
Let's define the keys as:
A=(a_0,a_1,…,a_i)  
B=(b_0,b_1,…,b_j)

Then the value of the combined key is:

C={c_i=a_(i%|A|)+b_(i%|B|)   |   0≤i≤lcd(|A|,|B|)}
```

And can be generalized to each number of keys:

```
C={c_i=a_(i%|A|)+b_(i%|B|)+...+z_(i%|Z|)   |   0≤i≤lcd(|A|,|B|,...,|Z|)}
```